# How to remove all characters after a specific character in python?

Tags: python, replace

I have a string. How do I remove all text after a certain character? (*In this case `...`*) 
The text after will **`...`** change so I that's why I want to remove all characters after a certain one.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

Split on your separator at most once, and take the first piece:

```
sep = '...'
stripped = text.split(sep, 1)[0]
```

You didn't say what should happen if the separator isn't present.  Both this and [Alex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/904753/4518341) will return the entire string in that case.

Comment: Request is "remove all the text after" the separator, not "get" that text, so I think you want [0], not [-1], in your otherwise excellent solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, as I'm sure Ayman & Alex's did as well, so thank you all.

Comment: Use rsplit() if you need to split by a character starting from the end of the string.

Comment: rsplit() actually answers the question if there are multiple occurrences of the separator

Answer (score 138):

Assuming your separator is '...', but it can be any string.

```
text = 'some string... this part will be removed.'
head, sep, tail = text.partition('...')

>>> print head
some string
```

If the separator is not found, `head` will contain all of the original string.

The [partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) function was added in Python 2.5.

> `S.partition(sep)` -> `(head, sep, tail)`
>
> Searches for the separator *sep* in *S*, and returns the part before it,
> the separator itself, and the part after it. If the separator is not
> found, returns *S* and two empty strings.

Comment: Yet another excellent solution -- are we violating TOOOWTDI?-) Maybe worth a timeit run to check...

Comment: .partition wins -- 0.756 usec per loop, vs 1.13 for .split (comment formatting doesn't really let me show the exact tests, but I'm using @Ayman's text and separator) -- so, +1 for @Ayman's answer!

Comment: and btw, for completeness, the RE-based solution is 2.54 usec, i.e., way slower than either @Ayman's or @Ned's.

Comment: partition wins if you're in 2.5 land :)  For us suckers stuck in 2.4, we have to live with relatively glacial slowness of split.

Comment: Example is really helpful.

Comment: Small improvement, you can simply discard the other values if you don't need them:

```head, *_ = text.partition('...')
```

Answer (score 33):

If you want to remove everything after the last occurrence of separator in a string I find this works well:

`<separator>.join(string_to_split.split(<separator>)[:-1])`

For example, if  `string_to_split` is a path like `root/location/child/too_far.exe` and you only want the folder path, you can split by `"/".join(string_to_split.split("/")[:-1])` and you'll get 
`root/location/child`

Comment: additionally, you can change that -1 to any index to be the occurrence at which you drop text.

Comment: this is the most flexible solution

Answer (score 11):

Without a regular expression (which I assume is what you want):

```
def remafterellipsis(text):
  where_ellipsis = text.find('...')
  if where_ellipsis == -1:
    return text
  return text[:where_ellipsis + 3]
```

or, with a regular expression:

```
import re

def remwithre(text, there=re.compile(re.escape('...')+'.*')):
  return there.sub('', text)
```

Comment: Might want to use sep='...' as a kwarg and use len(sep) instead of hard-coding the 3 to make it slightly more future-proof.

Comment: Yep, but then you need to recompile the RE on each call, so performance suffers for the RE solution (no real difference for the non-RE solution). Some generality is free, some isn't...;-)

Answer (score 6):

```py
import re
test = "This is a test...we should not be able to see this"
res = re.sub(r'\.\.\..*',"",test)
print(res)
```

Output: "This is a test"

Comment: kindly please explain

Answer (score 4):

The method find will return the character position in a string. Then, if you want remove every thing from the character, do this:

```
mystring = "123⋯567"
mystring[ 0 : mystring.index("⋯")]

>> '123'
```

If you want to keep the character, add 1 to the character position.

Answer (score 3):

From a file:

```
import re
sep = '...'

with open("requirements.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        res = line.split(sep, 1)[0]
        print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner for in-place replacement:

```
text, *_ = text.partition('...')
```

Credits to original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/904758/5726546

Answer (score 0):

> This is in python 3.7 working to me
> In my case I need to remove after dot in my  string variable fees

fees = 45.05
split_string = fees.split(".", 1)

substring = split_string[0]

print(substring)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to remove all characters after the *last* occurrence of a character in a string (assume that you want to remove all characters after the final '/').

```
path = 'I/only/want/the/containing/directory/not/the/file.txt'

while path[-1] != '/':
    path = path[:-1]
```

Comment: I think this will create a new copy of `path` at each iteration, so it's not a particularly efficient solution, although I agree it should work.

Answer (score -1):

another easy way using re will be

```
import re, clr

text = 'some string... this part will be removed.'

text= re.search(r'(\A.*)\.\.\..+',url,re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE).group(1)

// text = some string
```

Comment: Regular expressions are difficult because of the shorthand.  This might be a useful answer, but you didn't explain any of it.