# In Python 2.4, how can I strip out characters after ';'?

Tags: python, string, python-2.4

Let's say I'm parsing a file, which uses `;` as the comment character. I don't want to parse comments. So if I a line looks like this:

```
example.com.              600     IN      MX      8 s1b9.example.net ; hello!
```

Is there an easier/more-elegant way to strip chars out other than this:

```
rtr = ''
for line in file:
    trig = False
    for char in line:
        if not trig and char != ';':
            rtr += char
        else:
            trig = True
    if rtr[max(rtr)] != '\n':
        rtr += '\n'
```

Comment: Yes, python2.4. Should have mentioned that in the ??

Comment: well python2.4 is **two** versions behind current stable version. what do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all characters after a specific character in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I'd recommend saying

```
line.split(";")[0]
```

which will give you a string of all characters up to but not including the first ";" character.  If no ";" character is present, then it will give you the entire line.

Comment: I agree with @Jiri in using the maxsplit arg, i.e `line.split(";", 1)[0]`. It's faster (especially if you are parsing lots of text) because you don't end up having to split the entire text just for getting the first element.

Answer (score 20):

just do a split on the line by comment then get the first element
eg

```
line.split(";")[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python 2.5 or greater, I would use the [`partition`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) method:

```
rtr = line.partition(';')[0].rstrip() + '\n'
```

Comment: @ghostdog74: stable versions of python are 2.6 and 3.1

Comment: @SG, that's fine, but still, if one is still using <2.5++ in production, they will not have this luxury.

Comment: This answer was valid when I posted it because the OP had not yet mentioned that he was using Python 2.4 (now about five years old). I am not going to delete this answer because I find the fact that `partition` returns a fixed length vector a useful feature, although it does not matter much here.

Comment: Why is `partition` better?

Comment: @MattFletcher Think about what happens when you parse a line with thousands of fields and you just want the first.

Answer (score 4):

So you'll want to split the line on the first semicolon, take everything before it, strip off any lingering whitespace, and append a newline character.

```
rtr = line.split(";", 1)[0].rstrip() + '\n'
```

**Links to Documentation:**

- [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

Comment: links you provide and methods you use are not the same

Answer (score 3):

```
file = open(r'c:\temp\test.txt', 'r')
for line in file:   print
   line.split(";")[0].strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading, splitting, stripping, and joining lines with newline all in one line of python:

```
rtr = '\n'.join(line.split(';')[0].strip() for line in open(r'c:\temp\test.txt', 'r'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way :

```
In [6]: line = "foo;bar"
In [7]: line[:line.find(";")] + "\n"
Out[7]: 'foo\n'
```

Comment: if line == "fubar", that produces "fuba\n" ... correcting the problem in a one-liner produces this: `line[:None if line.find(";") == -1 else line.find(";")]` (which I'm certainly not proposing as a good idea at all).

Answer (score -3):

I have not tested this with python but I use similar code else where.

```
import re
content = open(r'c:\temp\test.txt', 'r').read()
content = re.sub(";.+", "\n")
```

Comment: your re.sub() is missing an argument and thus won't run -- very fortunate since **it would trash the first ';' in the file and everything after it**