# How to delete everything after a certain character in a string?

Tags: python, string, character, python-3.3

How would I delete everything after a certain character of a string in python? For example I have a string containing a file path and some extra characters. How would I delete everything after .zip? I've tried `rsplit` and `split` , but neither included the .zip when deleting extra characters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove all characters after a specific character in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just take the first portion of the split, and add `'.zip'` back:

```
s = 'test.zip.zyz'
s = s.split('.zip', 1)[0] + '.zip'
```

Alternatively you could use slicing, here is a solution where you don't need to add `'.zip'` back to the result (the `4` comes from `len('.zip')`):

```
s = s[:s.index('.zip')+4]
```

Or another alternative with regular expressions:

```
import re
s = re.match(r'^.*?\.zip', s).group(0)
```

Answer (score 11):

`str.partition`:

```
>>> s='abc.zip.blech'
>>> ''.join(s.partition('.zip')[0:2])
'abc.zip'
>>> s='abc.zip'
>>> ''.join(s.partition('.zip')[0:2])
'abc.zip'
>>> s='abc.py'
>>> ''.join(s.partition('.zip')[0:2])
'abc.py'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use slices:

```
s = 'test.zip.xyz'
s[:s.index('.zip') + len('.zip')]
=> 'test.zip'
```

And it's easy to pack the above in a little helper function:

```
def removeAfter(string, suffix):
    return string[:string.index(suffix) + len(suffix)]

removeAfter('test.zip.xyz', '.zip')
=> 'test.zip'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easy to create a simple lambda function for this.

```
mystrip = lambda s, ss: s[:s.index(ss) + len(ss)]
```

Can be used like this:

```
mystr = "this should stay.zipand this should be removed."
mystrip(mystr, ".zip") # 'this should stay.zip'
```

Comment: Isn't this simply Óscar López's answer?  I'm also not sure I see the point of using a `lambda` if you're going to immediately give it a name.

Comment: You're right but the answers showed up quickly and I didn't refreshed the page before posting.. F.J has also a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` module:

```
import re
re.sub('\.zip.*','.zip','test.zip.blah')
```