# eliminate text after certain character in python pipeline- with slice?

Tags: python, csv

This is a short script I've written to refine and validate a large dataset that I have.

```
# The purpose of this script is the refinement of the job data attained from the
# JSI as it is rendered by the `csv generator` contributed by Luis for purposes
# of presentation on the dashboard map. 

import csv

# The number of columns
num_headers = 9

# Remove invalid characters from records
def url_escaper(data):
  for line in data:
    yield line.replace('&','&amp;')

# Be sure to configure input & output files
with open("adzuna_input_THRESHOLD.csv", 'r') as file_in, open("adzuna_output_GO.csv", 'w') as file_out:
    csv_in = csv.reader( url_escaper( file_in ) )
    csv_out = csv.writer(file_out)

    # Get rid of rows that have the wrong number of columns
    # and rows that have only whitespace for a columnar value
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_in, start=1):
        if not [e for e in row if not e.strip()]:
            if len(row) == num_headers:
                csv_out.writerow(row)
        else:
            print "line %d is malformed" % i
```

I have one field that is structured like so:

`finance|statistics|lisp`

I've seen ways to do this using other utilities like [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847189/remove-text-after-final-period-in-string), but I want to ideally achieve the same effect within the scope of this python code.

Maybe I can iterate over all the characters of all the columnar values, perhaps as a list, and if I see a `|` I can dispose of the `|` and all the text that follows it within the scope of the column value.

I think surely it can be achieved with slices as they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891443/how-to-delete-everything-after-a-certain-character-in-a-string) but I don't quite understand how the indices with slices work- and I can't see how I could include this process harmoniously within the cascade of the current script pipeline.

With regex I guess it's something like this

```
(?:|)(.*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use string's `split` method?

```
In[4]: 'finance|statistics|lisp'.split('|')[0]
Out[4]: 'finance'
```

It does not fail with exception when you do not have separator character in the string too:

```
In[5]: 'finance/statistics/lisp'.split('|')[0]
Out[5]: 'finance/statistics/lisp'
```