# Delete rest of string after n-th occurence

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, python-2.x

I have the following string:

```
a = "this.is.a.string"
```

I wish to delete everything after the 3rd '.' symbol so that it returns

```
trim(a)
>>> "this.is.a"
```

while a string without the 3rd '.' should return itself.

This answer ([How to remove all characters after a specific character in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python)) was the closest solution I could find, however I don't think `split` would help me this time.

Comment: regex way, `re.sub(r'^((?:[^.]*\.){2}[^.]*)\..*', r'\1', a)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by the `dot` and then [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> ".".join(a.split(".")[:3])
'this.is.a'
```

You may also specify the `maxsplit` argument since you need only 3 "slices":

> If `maxsplit` is given, at most `maxsplit` splits are done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements).

```
>>> ".".join(a.split(".", 3)[:-1])
'this.is.a'
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a good use case for `maxsplit` to avoid unnecessary splitting if the string contains more than 2 dots.

Comment: With `maxsplit`, you can also use `[:-1]` as the slice, regardless of the value of `maxsplit`.

Answer (score 2):

*@alecxe*'s answer is sufficient, however, you ask

> Delete rest of string after n-th occurrence

To do that, you can do

```
def removeAfterN(yourStr, nth, occurenceOf):
    return occurenceOf.join(yourStr.split(occurenceOf)[:nth])
```

Where `yourStr` is your string, `nth` is the occurrence (in your example, it would be `3`), and `occurenceOf` would be `.` from your example.

```
>>> removeAfterN("this.is.a.string",3,".")
'this.is.a'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple regex here and [***sub***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

print re.sub(r'\.a.*$', '.a', a)
```

`\.a` means literally symbols `.a`

`.*$` means everything till the end

Or simple [***replace***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
a.replace('.string','')
```

More common solution with `re` might be:

```
print re.sub(r'(^[a-z]+\.[a-z]+)\..*$', '\g<1>', a)
```

We are grouping every part with `.` and slicing the 3rd one.

`[a-z]+` - means more than one letter

`\..*$` means everything from second `.` till the end

`\g<1>` means group reference to first group `()`

more detailed explanation on regex syntax you can find [***here***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: could you explain what the re expressions do?

Comment: added some explanation

Comment: I'm afraid all this does is get rid of the ".string" at the end. Try `a="this.is.all.of.a.a.string"' for example and you will see that only ".string" disappears with the last regex.

I need all of string after 3rd period deleted (period symbol included)

Answer (score -1):

```
def trim(s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '.'
             if count == 2
                  s = s[:i]
                  break
             count += 1
```