# Python regex substitute between parenthesis

Tags: regex, python-3.5

I need to read in lines from a text file, basically everything after and including the first open parenthesis can be removed with an empty string.
I came up with a regex:

```
>>> line = "Bar Harbor (College of the Atlantic)"
>>> re.sub(r"(.*) ?\(.*$","\1", line)
'\x01'
```

The following works, but excludes lines that do not have parentheses which is not according the specs (so it does not work)

```
match = re.match("(.*?) ?\(.*$",line)
if match:
    towns.append(match.group(1))
```

What am i doing wrong in te first substitute? Regexs are not necessary, I just need to remove everything after the first parentheses, so also if there is more than one way I'm also interested.

Comment: If all after *first* `(` should be removed, use `re.sub(r"\(.*","", line)`, why add `(.*) ?`?

Comment: or if you are gonna match do `(?m)^[^(]+`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I hope it's because I spent too much time behind the pc, maybe i should get sleep.

Comment: I think it is close to [How to remove all characters after a specific character in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without regular expressions:

```
In [1]: x = "Bar Harbor (College of the Atlantic)"

In [6]: idx = x.find('(')

In [7]: x[:idx] if idx > 0 else x
Out[7]: 'Bar Harbor '
```

Comment: This one [has already been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/904753/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Didn't know it was a dupe, feel free to close as duplicate.