# How to remove all characters from a string after two white spaces in python?

Tags: python, string

The string i needed to format is,

```
string = "How are you?     abcdef"
```

I need to remove the "abcdef" from the string.

Comment: `print(string.replace('abcdefg',''))`

Comment: Duplicate of [How to remove all characters after a specific character in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string = string.split('  ')[0]
```

Edit: Explanation. The line of code above will split the single string into a list of strings wherever there is a double space. It is important to note that whatever is split upon, will be removed. `[0]` then retrieves the first element in this newly formed list.

Comment: some explanation concerning the use of the double space would help the OP.  ditto for [0]