# How can I remove characters overflow from the target one

Tags: python, python-re

I'm **scraping** web but I'm stack with an error and I failed to handle it

I've the following url but can't work for me to make it work require to remove all characters
after `jpg` and I tried it with regular expression but I couldnt and I dont want to count
overflowing characters and index on url to remove it because it will not work on all
of image

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg/498px-Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
```

**this is the code I've tried so far**

```
regex = re.sub('[^*\w]/+\w', '', image)

# and

sep = 'jpg/'
rest = image.split(sep, 1)[0]
print(rest)
```

but I failed and I also check here [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904746/how-to-remove-all-characters-after-a-specific-character-in-python) but I can't find any solution because of my url contains weird and similar characters.

**an expected result looks like this**

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will stop the match at the first occurrence of `.jpg` in the given URL.

```
import re

url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg/498px-Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg"
regex = r"^https?://[^\s/$.?#].[^\s]*?(?:\.jpg)"
result = re.match(regex, url)
print(result.group())
```

**Output:**

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
```

https://regex101.com/r/i6mu3z/1

Answer (score 1):

You can try splitting the URL based on `/` and remove the last part and join back using `/`.

Something like:

```
# Input
i_string = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg/498px-Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg"
print(i_string)

# Approach 1
res = "/".join(i_string.split("/")[:-1])
print(res)


# Approach 2, using function
def remove_last_part(i_string: str) -> str:
    return "/".join(i_string.split("/")[:-1])


print(remove_last_part(i_string))
```

Result

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg/498px-Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
```

Since you want to remove all the chars after `jpg`, you can do something like following:

```
# Input
i_string = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg/498px-Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg"
print(i_string)

def remove_last_part(i_string: str, delimiter: str) -> str:
    return delimiter.join(i_string.split(delimiter)[:1]) + delimiter


print(remove_last_part(i_string, "jpg"))
```

Result:

```
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg/498px-Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lebron_wizards_2017_%28cropped%29.jpg
```